# ASP.NET Web Forms site doesn't load correctly on the mobile devices

Tags: c#, asp.net, iphone, webforms

I have a site which is written in asp.net web forms framework which doesn't load correctly on the mobile devices

Maybe some one could suggest something what can be done to this site potentially to load it correctly into a mobile device

I am not even sure where to start

Comment: Define "not loading correctly" perhaps?

Comment: The header ends up on a very bottom, top nav items get squashed to the left on top of the logo, the bottom section ends on the left side

Comment: That all sound like a website that was not build for mobile. Maybe use Bootstrap or something similar and rebuild/redesign your website.

Comment: do you have  site master, and a site.mobile master page? I would consider deleting the site.mobile master page. With even a relative older site, phone browsers now have quite high resolution, and often it's better to use the standard pages rendered for desktop on the mobile device. You of course will have to test this, since deleting the site.mobile master page might have been actually setup. In most cases (or at least rather often), the mobile master page is created by default, but not used. If that is your use case, then delete/remove the site.mobile master page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did figure out the issue. These are the things I did

1. Removed all instances of `float:left;` style from the center content
2. Hid most controls on the header using the `@media (max-width:600px)` style
3. Applied smaller fonts and shorter widths to the left nav and the center contents using the `@media (min-width:600px)` and `@media (max-width:600px)`  styles